# python replacing lines in a file with nothing

Tags: python, replace

I want to delete some specific lines in a file. The below code doesn't seem to work. There are no errors thrown but this code won't delete the lines that are meant to be deleted.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
import re
import string

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("input", help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*')  
args = p.parse_args()
kkk_list = args.input # ['1.1.1.1:443:myname', '2.2.2.2:443:yourname']


def getStringInFormat(ip, port, name):
    formattedText = "HOST Address:{ip}:PORT:{port}\n"\
                    "   server tcp\n"\
                    "   server {ip}:{port} name {name}\n\n".format(ip=ip, 
                                                                port=port, 
                                                              name=name)

    return formattedText

with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    fileContent = f.read()

    # below two lines delete old content of file
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()

    for kkk in kkk_list:
        ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)

        stringNeedsToBeDeleted = getStringInFormat(ip, port, name)
        fileContent = fileContent.replace(stringNeedsToBeDeleted, "")

    f.write(fileContent)
```

The content of the file from which I'm trying to delete looks like following. Please note the space before 2nd and 3rd lines

```
------------do not delete this line------

HOST Address:1.1.1.1:PORT:443\n"\

     server tcp\n"\
     server 1.1.1.1:443 name myname1

--------------- do not delete this line either
```

If the script is successful the file should look like below where there is only one new line in between.

```
------------do not delete this line------

------------do not delete this line either ----
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything correct in your file editing loop, which means that if you aren't actually replacing anything its because the string you are looking for doesn't exist.  Indeed, when you tell us that you are looking for this string:

```
------------do not delete this line------

HOST Address:1.1.1.1:PORT:443\n"\

     server tcp\n"\
     server 1.1.1.1:443 name myname1

--------------- do not delete this line either
```

It doesn't appear to match up with the string you are trying to match it with:

```
formattedText = "HOST Address:{ip}:PORT:{port}\n"\
                "   server tcp\n"\
                "   server {ip}:{port} name {name}\n\n"
```

Keep in mind in order to replace this string with your current code, the strings have to *exactly* match, in this case I don't see the \n between "HOST Addess..." and "   server tcp\n"\ or the \ lines.  But I suspect those were just formatting errors on your part.

If you really want to get to the root of this problem I suggest you find a string you know for certain you are trying to delete and test your code with that to make sure the strings are the same.  Here is an example.  If you want to find:

```
HOST Address:1.1.1.1:PORT:443

    server tcp

    server 1.1.1.1:443 name myname1
```

Then compare with your search string via:

```
test_string = # the string I posted above, you should probably 
              # grab this from a file for consistency. 
kkk = '1.1.1.1:443:myname'
ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)
assert ip == '1.1.1.1'
assert port == '443' 
assert name == 'myname'
stringNeedsToBeDeleted = getStringInFormat(ip, port, name)
assert stringNeedsToBeDeleted == test_string, "Error, strings are not equal!"
```

This should give you a clue into what the actual problem is. `myname1`, which I grabbed directly from your example, doesn't match up with your match string.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file in read mode 'r+'. You need to open it in write mode 'w' to write to it. Or just don't specify a mode.

Comment: thanks but it's not "r" but "r+" which is for read and write.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the contents of your file to a list, write over the old file, mutate your list, and then write the list to the file.

```
import argparse
import re
import string

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("input", help="input the data in format ip:port:name",nargs='*')  
args = p.parse_args()
kkk_list = args.input # ['1.1.1.1:443:myname', '2.2.2.2:443:yourname']


def getStringInFormat(ip, port, name):
     formattedText = "HOST Address:{ip}:PORT:{port}\n"\
                "   server tcp\n"\
                "   server {ip}:{port} name {name}\n\n".format(ip=ip, 
                                                            port=port, 
                                                          name=name)

     return formattedText

with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    for kkk in kkk_list:
        ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)

        stringNeedsToBeDeleted = getStringInFormat(ip, port, name)
        fileContent = fileContent.replace(stringNeedsToBeDeleted, "")

        f.write(fileContent) #now, your file contains all the host addressed and IPs


f = open("file.txt").readlines()

contents = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in f]
new_file = open('file.txt', 'w')
new_file.write('')

new_file.write(''.join(contents[0]))
new_file.write('\n\n\n')
new_file.write(contents[''.join(len(contents)-1])))

new_file.close()
```

Comment: thanks a lot. sounds right . I will try this out tomorrow and provide a feed back.  However I still like to attempt this without opening multiple files. I've seen the approach I have taken has been proven to work on few forums,  but not sure why I can't get mine to work. Perhaps it has to do with all the spaces and new lines within the block I want to get rid of, hmm. Thanks again for the great suggestion sir

Comment: You are welcome! I have edited the question to cut down on the number of times you have to open the file.

Comment: Ajax1234. Thanks so much. Can you please integrate what you've suggested to my code block so that I can connect the dots and understands the code better. Sorry I'm not a seasoned python developer hence the request.

Comment: No problem! I edited the code above, see what you think. All it does is write the host and IP info to the file, then runs the new code, which overwrites the middle portion, just leaving the top and bottom guidelines, as requested.